# Create a nested list of my WordPress pages, including the last modified date for each page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of all the WordPress pages I'm using on my site. I want to nest them and include the last modified date.

I'm using this code and placing it at the end of my functions.php file:

```
function wpb_last_modified_date( $post_id ) {
    $last_modified = get_the_modified_time( 'F jS, Y' );
    return $last_modified;
}

function wpb_list_pages() {
    $pages = get_pages();
    $result = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
        $last_modified = wpb_last_modified_date( $page->ID );
        $result .= '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $page->ID ) . '">' . $page->post_title . '</a> (Last modified: ' . $last_modified . ')</li>';
    }
    $result .= '</ul>';
    return $result;
}
add_shortcode( 'list_pages', 'wpb_list_pages' );
```

then i add this shortcode to a WordPress page:

[list_pages]

but saving the page, I receive the error:

"Updating failed. The response is not a valid JSON response."

I'm not sure what is happening. I thought it was all good.

Comment: Consider having your browser developer tools open and recreate the error – you could then look in the console or the *Network* tab for a look at what the response actually is and this might give you some clues on what has gone wrong. Also, you could look on the server side (such as error logs) or try debugging for further information on the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Not related to the error, but you forgot to pass the post ID to `get_the_modified_time`.